# MS Access Grouped Percentage Calculation

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Not sure how to best to explain this one but I have a table that for example looks like this:

```
Date        WebSitePage  Visits
01/01/2016  Visits       50
01/01/2016  Basket       40
01/01/2016  CheckOut     35
01/01/2016  ThankYou     25
02/01/2016  Visits       43
02/01/2016  Basket       23
02/01/2016  CheckOut     20
02/01/2016  ThankYou     12
```

As you can see they are website pages (fictional for this example). I want to create a query, be it access query with a calculation or SQL or VBA (limited as you cant use a CASE statement in Access SQL), to calculate the WebSitePage conversion percentage e.g Basket/CheckOut, then CheckOut/ThankYou and also a visits conversion of ThankYou/Visits etc.

I'm struggling how to compile the query or write the calculation.
Its simple in Excel typically. But I also dont want to split the WebSitePage out into separate columns.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query to get the 4 different counts in 4 different columns to make the task easier:

```sql
SELECT   [Date],
         Sum(IIf(WebSitePage = "Visits", Visits, 0))   AS Visits,
         Sum(IIf(WebSitePage = "Basket", Visits, 0))   AS Basket,
         Sum(IIf(WebSitePage = "CheckOut", Visits, 0)) AS CheckOut,
         Sum(IIf(WebSitePage = "ThankYou", Visits, 0)) AS ThankYou
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Note that with [`IIf`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) you can solve issues where you would use `CASE WHEN` expressions in more ISO-compliant SQL databases.

If you save the above statement as a Query in MS Access (let's call it MyQuery), then you can do things like this:

```sql
SELECT   [Date],
         100*Basket/CheckOut   AS Basket_CheckOut_Pct,
         100*CheckOut/ThankYou AS CheckOut_ThankYou_Pct,
         100*ThankYou/Visits   AS ThankYou_Visits_Pct
FROM     MyQuery
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, I'll give a crack now and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Hi, not had chance to try it out yet as I have been working on a diferent project the last few weeks. Should be back onto this next week so I will come back and let you know. Thank you :)